# SSL encryption for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

I am new to SSL and I have to include it in my C# ASP.NET web application. The procedure I need to achieve is as follows and starts with a string variable:

1. Convert the content of a string variable to BASE64. I already did this step.
2. I have to process the result in step (1) with SSL using a ".key" file and a ".cer" file that we already have. A new string is generated in this step.
3. SHA1 must be applied to the result in step (2). Here I get the final result.

Do not ask me why all these encryption steps, it is something that must be done this way, it is a requirement. The issue I have is in step (2) because I have no idea of how to approach it.

Comment: Can you add link to what you mean "SSL encryption"?

Comment: I have been reviewing the instructions of what I have to do and probably I am misunderstanding the real meaning of the procedure. I will make sure about all this and write another comment for this question.